# Reading Csv file written by Dataframewriter Pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I was having dataframe which I wrote to a CSV by using below code:

```
df.write.format("csv").save(base_path+"avg.csv")
```

As i am running spark in client mode, above snippets created a folder name avg.csv and the folder contains some file with part-*
.csv on my worker node or nested folder then file part-*.csv.

Now when I am trying to read avg.csv I am getting path doesn't exist.

```
df.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load(base_path+"avg.csv")
```

Can anybody tell where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`Part-00**` files  are output of distributively computed files (like MR, spark). So, it will be always a folder created with part files when you try to store, as this is an output of some distributed storage which is to be kept in mind.

So, try using:

```
df.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load(base_path+"avg.csv/*")
```

Comment: When I performed this i get File not Found exception: part-00*.csv doesn't exist on executor 2. Although this exist in one of my node in cluster